# c# xna 4.0 spritebatch error

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Project
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
       SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Texture2D myTexture;
        Rectangle myRectangle;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()

        {


            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);


            Texture myTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("character");

            myRectangle = new Rectangle(10, 100, 30, 50);
            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here
            spriteBatch.Begin();

            spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture,myRectangle,Color.White);

            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my code but this returns a error on debug which will highlight

```
spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture,myRectangle,Color.White);
```

and tell 
ArgumentNullExcerption was unhandled
This method does not accept null for this parameter.
Parameter name: texture
what is the error?

Comment: -1 this question is virtually identical to your last question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LoadContent you create a new variable and assign the texture to it and myTexture stays null.

replace

```
Texture myTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("character");
```

with

```
myTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("character");
```